# query to find diff between two records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following tables

```
movies
  - id

details
  - user_id 
  - movie_id 
  - rating

users
  - id
```

detail belongs to user and movie

I want to find the the diff between the rating of two users say id 3,10

simply I want answer of this

```
sum(10-(user1.rating - user2.rating))
   where rating is > 0
```

i.e both users should have given at-least non zero rating

Comment: You could use subqueries and retrive the rating of each users

Comment: @Brewal isn't it possible with joins?

Comment: Why would you want to use joins ?

Comment: @Brewal can you help with a sample query?

Comment: The solution of tombom looks good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
d1.movie_id
, d1.rating as user1Rating
, d2.rating as user2Rating
, abs(d1.rating - d2.rating)
from
details d1
inner join details d2 on d1.movie_id = d2.movie_id
where d1.user_id = 1
and d2.user_id = 2
```

[See it working live in an sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09e26/10/0)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE ratings
(   userId int, movieId int, rating int)

INSERT INTO ratings (userId, movieId, rating) VALUES
    (3, 1, 5), (10, 1, 8),
    (3, 2, 10), (10, 2, 3)

SELECT r1.movieId, (r1.rating - r2.rating) FROM ratings as r1
INNER JOIN ratings as r2 on r1.movieId = r2.movieId
WHERE r1.userId = 3 and r2.userId = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @UserRating1 int
DECLARE @UserRating2 int
DECLARE @UserID1 int
DECLARE @UserID2 int
DECLARE @MovieID int

SET @MovieID = 99
SET @UserID1 = 3
SET @UserID2 = 10

SET @UserRating1 = (SELECT Rating FROM details WHERE movie_id = @MovieID AND user_id = @UserID1 AND Rating > 0)
SET @UserRating2 = (SELECT Rating FROM details WHERE movie_id = @MovieID AND user_id = @UserID2  AND Rating > 0)

PRINT @UserRating1 - @UserRating2
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I replace the syntax from MSSQL to MySql

You can check this on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/5d2d8/1):

```
create table movies (id int);
insert into movies (id) values (1);
insert into movies (id) values (2);
insert into movies (id) values (3);
insert into movies (id) values (4);
insert into movies (id) values (5);

create table users (id int);
insert into users (id) values (1);
insert into users (id) values (2);
insert into users (id) values (3);
insert into users (id) values (4);
insert into users (id) values (5);
insert into users (id) values (10);

create table details (user_id int, movie_id int, rating int);

insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (3,1,1);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (3,2,2);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (3,3,3);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (3,4,1);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (3,5,4);

insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (10,1,3);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (10,2,1);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (10,3,2);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (10,4,1);
insert into details (user_id, movie_id, rating) values (10,5,5);
```

and

```
select 
  sum(10-(details1.rating - details2.rating))
from
  movies
  inner join details details1 on movies.id = details1.movie_id
  inner join users user1 on details1.user_id = user1.id 
  inner join details details2 on movies.id = details2.movie_id
  inner join users user2 on details2.user_id = user2.id 
where 
  (user1.id=3) 
  and
  (user2.id=10)
  and
  (details1.rating is not null) and (details1.rating > 0)
  and
  (details2.rating is not null) and (details2.rating > 0)
```